# jQuery: set data attribute of element from within onchange-function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm having a hard time setting a data-attribute of an element when called from an onchange-function.
My setup is this:

```
$('#my_element').data('query-parameters', {'var': 'value'});
```

"query_parameters" is used by a select2-component used with Symfony and the tetranz/select2entity-bundle. The AJAX-request sent out by select2 should contain "value" from another form-element that will be entered before.

As expected, the "data-query-parameters" is not set in the DOM (but that's by design as I've learned), so I checked it via console log, it's `Object { var: "" }` before setting it (var is set to be empty from the controller) and `Object { var: "value" }` afterwards, so that seems to work alright. Also the select2-AJAX-request transmits "value" back to my controller.

Now: As I need to change the query-parameters depending on another input-field, I put the above code in an onchange-function like this:

```
$('#another_element').change(function () {
    $('#my_element').data('query-parameters', {'var': 'value'});
    // check input and send AJAX-request from select2
}
```

Again I checked the content of data-query-parameters with console.log, the output is the same as outside the onchange-function (empty before executing data(), filled afterwards), BUT: while the parameter for the select2-request is set when calling data() outside onchange() (just for testing), the parameter always remains empty in the request when data() is called inside onchange().

To test this further, I have extracted the changing of query-parameters to a function:

```
function changeQueryParams(text) {
    console.log($('#my_element').data('query-parameters'));
    $('#my_element').data('query-parameters', {'var': text});
    console.log($('#my_element').data('query-parameters'));
}
```

I called the above function once on pageload (with text='check1') and then in the onchange-event (text='check2'). The console-output is this:

```
Object { var: "" }
Object { var: "check1" }
Object { var: "check1" }
Object { var: "check2" }
```

Everything seems to be fine, first "var" is empty, after pageload changeQueryParams() sets it to "check1", after the onchange-event it changes from "check1" to "check2". But when the select2-request is done, I receive "check1" as the value of "var" in my controller ...

So the question is: Why is there a difference? Why does console.log show the change in the attribute but the select2-request doesn't recognize it? Is there a scope that I have to mind?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why this happens: This is not a jQuery- but rather a Select2-problem in the symfony bundle.

In select2entity.js (which comes with the bundle), the select2-fields are initalized with `$('.select2entity[data-autostart="true"]').select2entity();`, but this only happens once on document.ready, so in the onchange-method data-query-parameters are correctly set, but not read (again) by the select2-field.

So my workaround for now (filed a report on github to check if the maintainers will object or come up with a better solution) is to also call the initialization-method onchange, so the data can be transfered again - which makes everything work as expected, the changed data from "#another_element" is now sent to the server.

TLDR;
change

```
$('#another_element').change(function () {
    $('#my_element').data('query-parameters', {'var': 'value'});
    // check input and send AJAX-request from select2
}
```

to

```
$('#another_element').change(function () {
    $('#my_element').data('query-parameters', {'var': 'value'});
    $('.select2entity[data-autostart="true"]').select2entity();
    // check input and send AJAX-request from select2
}
```